# Recuperar los valores de una petición ajax, me duelve undefined al user el método get de un map

Tags: javascript, jquery, map

Hago una petición ajax, y recupero la información, pero luego no puedo pintar los valores recuperados, me devuelve todo el rato undefinded.

```
function ajaxCall() {
    let map = new Map();
    $.ajax({
      url: "api/path",
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(res) {
        map.set('facetUid', res.data.facetUid);
        map.set('userFacetid',res.data.userFacetid);
        map.set('userId',res.data.userId);
        map.set('authId', res.data.authId);
        map.set('baseUrl', res.data.baseUrl);
      }
    });
    return map;
  }
  var responseData = ajaxCall();
  console.log(responseData.get('authId'));
```

Si hago `console.log(responseData)` si me indica que es un objeto de tipo map y veo que tiene todos los elementos recibidos de la petición.

```
Map(0)

size: 5
​
<entries>
​​
Map(0)
​
size: 5
​
<entries>
​​
0: facetUid → "xxxxxxxxxx"
​​
1: userFacetId → "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
​​
2: userId → "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx"
​​
3: authId → "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx"
​​
4: baseUrl → "https://xxx.xxxx.com"​

<prototype>: Map.prototype { … }
​   ​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

​
Pero cuando si intento recuperar un valor vía .get me indica undefined

Comment: Por favor coloca la el resultado del `console.log(responseData)`. Saludos.

Comment: @JosueArriola Ya he añadido la la salida de console.log();

Answer (score 0):

recuerda que las peticiones AJAX deben especificar el tipo de contenido que esperas.

EJ para adicionar a tu AJAX.

```
 dataType: 'JSON'
```

Por otra parte puedes aplicar debajo de success: function(res) {

```
var res = JSON.parse(res);
```

Si aplicas un console.log sobre "res" y te retorna el texto, solo te falta realizar el parse para que JS lo pueda interpretar como un arreglo y no como una cadena de texto.